# Function return values in the Visual Studio 2013 debugger - not displayed

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have recently updated my VS2013 Professional with Update 2. Since I've updated, I can't see the function return values in the Autos window. When I type in the Immediate window $ReturnValue, I get a response of "Could not evaluate expression".
I recall that this new VS2013 feature use to work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem after updating to VS2013 Update 3.  To solve it I deleted the solution's corresponding .suo file (which might be hidden) and then it all worked again.